# How to replace data = TSFE:sys_language_uid in TYPO3 9 with aspects

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

We've had a typoscript configuration to tell the CSS in which language we are, adding a class into the body tag with a classnames `language-x`.

Since nothing seems to be documented about how to do this in Typoscript, I haven't tried much to solve this yet.

To do so, we used this typoscript:

```
// Language
    30 = TEXT
    30 {
        data = TSFE:sys_language_uid
        noTrimWrap = | language-||
    }
```

This now raises a `E_USER_DEPRECATED`:

```
Property $TSFE->sys_language_uid is not in use anymore as this information is now stored within the language aspect
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Thomi

Answer (score 5):

@josef-glatz as you suggested, I think this works too.

In Thomi's case, I suggest using:

```
// Language
    30 = TEXT
    30 {
        data = sitelanguage:languageId
        noTrimWrap = | language-||
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This is only available since TYPO3 **9.5.4**, since Georg Ringer only fixed the issue on 28.12.2018.

Answer (score 4):

**Since TYPO3 9.5.3** it's also possible to access the current site language configuration with TypoScript Setup:

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.data = siteLanguage:navigationTitle
page.10.wrap = This is the title of the current site language: |
```

or

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.dataWrap = The current site language direction is {siteLanguage:direction}
```

---

> See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/9.5.x/Feature-86973-TypoScriptGetTextPropertySiteLanguage.html for the detailed documentation about the functionality.

Comment: Does this really answer the question which was to replace TSFE:sys_language_uid?

Comment: Thank you @SybillePeters. My example was really no good select. But it give an example, that you can access siteLanguage:languageId as suggested in one of the answers after mine.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInTypoScript.html

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInConditions.html#sitehandling-inconditions

I think you can use a condition like:

```
[siteLanguage("typo3Language") == "it"]
  page.bodyTag = <body class="language-it">
[global]
```

Please take note that TYPO3 9.5 already puts the current language in the `<html>` tag, like: `<html lang="it">`

So you could use an [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) (very well supported) in your css:

```
html[lang="it"]{
/*css code here*/
}
```

Comment: I would generally reduce using conditions as much as possible. Using TypoScript CASE is better then using condition tags.